# Showing data from a List to a razor View

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, .net-core

I want to show all the values of my list(strings) to a razor view but without using a "foreach" method.

I've got this but the only thig remaining to show is a `List<Answer>`.

```
   @Model PoolManager.Models.Question
 @{
ViewData["Title"] = "Details";
}
<h2>Details</h2>
<table class="table">
<thead>
    <tr class="bg-primary">
        <th>Question</th>
        <th>Answers</th>
        <th>Starting Date</th>
        <th>Ending Date</th>
        <th>Active</th>
        <th>Details</th>
        <th>Edit</th>
        <th>Delete</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class="bg-info">@Model.Text</td>
        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Answers.Count; i++)
        {
            String Resposta = Model.Answers[i].ToString();
            <td class="bg-info" @Resposta></td>
        }

        <td class="bg-info">@Model.StartDate</td>
        <td class="bg-info">@Model.EndDate</td>
        <td>
            <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@Model">Edit</a> |
            <a asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@Model.Id">Details</a> |
            <a asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@Model.Id">Delete</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

I have this until now but it's only counting the number of the answers, but I need to output the answer not the id of it.

```
  @for (int i = Model.Answers.Count; i >= 0; i--)
  {          
      String Resposta = Model.Answers.ToString();

      <td class="bg-info" @Resposta></td>
  }
```

The output im getting is:

> system.collections.generic.list`1[poolmanager.models.answer]

Comment: Why do you not want to use foreach, any reason?

Comment: What's your reasoning for not wanting to use foreach (assuming also "for" isn't what you are looking for as well).

Comment: Welcome to SO. As I can see you have an HTML table. I could assume that  each row of this table is associated with an item in the list of answers. If that's true, I don't see how you could create that table, without looping through the list of answers.

Comment: @BenKrueger Acctualy i want to do it with a for

Comment: You're ok with a for loop but not a foreach loop? That's the most inane statement I've heard all day.

Comment: @TJWolschon was not my call, im a intership and my "boss" told me to do soo, and when I use foreach i get an error on Model

Comment: please edit your question and show your model.

Comment: @DaImTo in my model i'm only declaring "Id", "Answers" and "Votes"

Comment: Then what exactly do you want to loop over?

Comment: @DaImTo over the Model.Answers..
I have this until now:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you should fix your table section, looks bad now.

Second, you can't use a table if you want to show just 1 item, that's nonsense.

Third;
In your Controller's

> `ActionResult MyPage(){}`

method, you can send a list of answers by temporary usages.

```
public ActionResult MyPage(){

     List<PoolManager.Models.Question> questionList = dbModel.Questions.ToList();

     TempData['answerList'] = dbModel.Answers/*.Where(//IF YOU WANT A WHERE CLAUSE YOU CAN WRITE HERE AS WELL)*/.ToList();
     //We just sent List<Answers> inside that TempData["answerList"], we will cast it in RazorPage later.

     return View(questionList);
}
```

And after doing that, you should use

> `@model List<PoolManager.Models.Question>`

at the top of your Razor page.
Because we're sending a list of `PoolManager.Models.Question` objects.
And here I'm assuming you're using Bootstrap Modal. If not, you can use this as a div inside for each Answer cells and another table in those divs.
Let's look at my way:

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr class="bg-primary">
            <th>Question</th>
            <th>Answers</th>
            <th>Starting Date</th>
            <th>Ending Date</th>
            <th>Active</th>
            <th>BUTTON LINKS</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach(var question in Model)
        {
        <tr>
            <td class="bg-info">@question.Text</td>
            <td class="bg-info">
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" data-target="#myModalId_@question.questionId" data-toggle="modal">Answers</a>
            </td>
            <td class="bg-info">@question.StartDate</td>
            <td class="bg-info">@question.EndDate</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>
            <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@question">Edit</a> |
            <a asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@question.Id">Details</a> | 
            <a asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@question.Id">Delete</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

We just completed table section, let's fill inside modals.
You need to cast TempData["answerList"] to List class that we described in Controller before.

```
@foreach(var question in Model)
{
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModalId_@question.questionId" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalId_@question.questionId">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalId_@question.questionId">Looking at @question.Text 's answers</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    @foreach(var answer in ((List<Answers>)TempData["answerList"]).ToList() )
                    {
                        <div class="row">
                            @answer.Text
                        </div>
                    }
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

I hope this helps you a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Inside for loop you can fetch the value for each Answer in list using index. For Example :

```
 @for (int i = Model.Answers.Count; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        string Resposta = Model.Answers[i].ToString();
        <td class="bg-info">@Resposta</td>
    }
```

The above code will help you fetch value stored at every index using for loop itself.

Comment: I'm getting an error using this.
The error is: "ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index"

Comment: Try this for(int i = Model.Answers.Count-1; i >= 0; i--).           This will resolve this exception and your code will work fine

Comment: How can I give variable "i" value of 0 So i can do it in a crescent order instead of decrescent?

Comment: (int i = 0; i< Model.Answers.Count; i++).   Try this

Comment: I get no error but the result is "<td class="bg-info" poolmanager.models.answer=""></td>" why isn't it getting me the value ?

Comment: Please provide the view code. <td class="bg-info" @Resposta></td> if you have done this please modify this to <td class="bg-info">@Resposta</td>

Comment: Please update this line

     <td class="bg-info" @Resposta></td>

To

     <td class="bg-info" >@Resposta</td>

Place variable between "@Resposta" between td tag

<td>'Your variable here'</td>

Comment: What is the datatype of **Model.Answers**. Is it List<string> or List of any class. Please provide your model class.

Comment: From the image attached, it seems that PoolManager.Models.Answer is an object so you can show the value of property which you want in this way

Model.Answers[i].[PropertyName].ToString();